# Why does rails generate controller create these gets in routes for each database item?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I've run the lines

```
rails g model Post user_id:integer title_id:integer:index story:text tags:string eol:datetime
rails g controller Post user_id:integer title_id:integer:index story:text tags:string eol:datetime
```

and it has created the following routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'post/user_id:integer'

  get 'post/title_id:integer:index'

  get 'post/story:text'

  get 'post/tags:string'

  get 'post/eol:datetime'

  devise_for :users
  root :to => "visitors#index"
end
```

and the following controller

```
class PostController < ApplicationController
  def user_id:integer
  end

  def title_id:integer:index
  end

  def story:text
  end

  def tags:string
  end

  def eol:datetime
  end
end
```

I'm puzzled at why it would do this this way.  Is this for API requests?  I'm used to the controller having the typical `index`, `new`, `update` CRUD stuff.  Was it because I was supposed to leave them off of the generate command?  And even so, could this be a way to generate an API?

And last question I've seen :index tagged on model's before but I don't understand it's purpose, or how it will help.

But the only question that needs to be answered to this question is why the routes were generated this way.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
rails g controller Post action_name1, action_name2
```

It considers then as the controller actions. So in your command:

```
rails g controller Post user_id:integer title_id:integer:index story:text tags:string eol:datetime
```

your attributes are being considered as actions.

And so will be the routes generated.

And if you want rails to set model, controller, views and routes for you automatically with only 1 command then use:

```
rails g scaffold Post user_id:integer title_id:integer:index story:text tags:string eol:datetime
```

(ref: bbozo)

Feel free to ask more I you didn't understand it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably wanted to do

```
rails g scaffold Post user_id:integer title_id:integer:index story:text tags:string eol:datetime
```

Comment: I does seem that `rails g controller Post` doesn't include any of the CRUD

Comment: Yeah, `rails g controller` generates controller actions and iirc their views, when no params given it will generate a CRUD controller - http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails/Built-In_Rails_Tools/Generators#Generate_a_Controller

Answer (score 0):

```
rails g model Post
```

will consider `user_id:integer title_id:integer:index story:text tags:string eol:datetime` as `attributes` for `Post` Model

and

`rails g controller Post` will consider `user_id:integer title_id:integer:index story:text tags:string eol:datetime` as `actions` for `Post` Model

for CRUD `Scaffold` is best feature in rails... for more details you can read **[Ruby on Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)** official tutorail by Rails ;)